# Eclipse, how to generate "auto-makefile" for a project

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I'm new to eclipse, I would like to know if it's possible to update a makefile automatically on Eclipse.

If I create a new project, "test.cpp", a makefile is generated and that's correct. But if I add a new class in this project, we have to update the makefile or Eclipse can manage it? Because when I test it, I get a "recipe for taget 'test' failed" error

Thanks you
I hope it will help beginners like me

Comment: Which type of eclipse project you created? A c++ managed build?

Comment: No i just created (for this example) a new "Exectuable->Empty Project" and added a new class to this project, that's not the correct way?